# For the equation below, how would I calculate the gain required for a settling time of 1 s?

Tags: control, control-system, control-theory

The equation is:

\$G=\dfrac{k(s+4)}{(s+1)(s^2+6s+13)}\$

How would I calculate the gain (k) required for a settling time of 1 s?

By using \$ts=\dfrac{4}{(ωζk)}\$  the closest value I got was `k = 4/3`, however, this value is incorrect when using MATLAB to confirm the answer.

Below is my hand calculation

[image: Here is my hand calc]

Comment: I don't see k in your top equation. Are you in fact using the top formula wrapped around with negative feedback where k is the amount of negative feedback. Maybe it's best if you draw a block diagram? You should also show the way you came to your answer.

Comment: I've edited your top equation (using mathjax/latex) to make it easier to read. Maybe you can follow this lead and do the same for the other equation?

Comment: Is this a question regarding school? Or something else? And is this within 2% or 5% or what? How do you define `settling time`? Really sounds like homework to me. But I'm open to being wrong about it.

Comment: This is part of a uni assignment. I K is a constant that is multiplied against G, I will edit the equation to clarify.

Comment: Where does the expression for ts comes from?  Does it really apply for your system (third order) ?

Comment: In honesty I am not sure. The equation was given in lecture and was stated to be the settling time. However all examples have second order systems. This is where I am struggling. I did attempt to use the dominant poles theory, however the solution gave an even bigger settling time.